# RSpec with Capybara - test signing in with OpenID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, capybara, omniauth

I am creating request specs following the Railscast at http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

In my application, users sign in using their Google OpenID accounts with OmniAuth (http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth). How can I test this with RSpec and Capybara? When my application redirects to the Google sign in page, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches "/accounts/o8/ud"
```

It seems that it doesn't allow redirecting away from the application, so how should I test this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no experience with Capybara and can therefore not comment on your question, however, I have saved a bookmark for later usage that may be useful to you: http://blog.zerosum.org/2011/03/19/easy-rails-outh-integration-testing.html

Comment: yeah, nice one. Using `OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:twitter, `